# Phaser rendering

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am making a game in javascript using Phaser that has a map that is 11800 x 11800 pixels. This comes to about 394.5 mb. This is too large to render with 8 gigs of ram, so I split it into 100 pieces (1180 x 1180 each being a 10x10 grid).

Does Phaser render images off screen, or should I write code to only render when in range of camera, and image.kill(); when not. Or is there a better way of handling this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check a Phaser example to handle out of bounds elements [here](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/sprites/out-of-bounds).
Basically you have to handle the out of bounds event for each element.

About how to handle a huge map, it depends of what kind of game you are creating: usually the approach is using tiles from a spritesheet, which allows you to create huge maps without big files (example [here](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/tilemaps/map-collide)):

Answer (score 0):

Phaser does not automatically check for objects visibility before rendering them, that is something you have to handle yourself.

There is a function in Phaser.Component called inCamera which allows you to check if the game object is inside the camera bounds.

http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Component.InCamera.html

Running this on every game object can cause performance issues if you're constantly checking them, so depending on the logic of your game I would try to keep the checks as low as possible.